# Missing directives or an assembly in web service

Tags: web-services, wcf

Sometimes adding a WCF Service Reference generates an empty reference.cs

I'm getting below error message after updating service reference.

> are you missing using directives or an assembly reference?

i tried below steps as well

right-click service reference and click configure and uncheck "Reuse Types in Referenced Assemblies" .

Comment: Hello Any suggestion on my question?

Comment: While asking question, provide more info such as code snippet, tags so more people can see the question and you might get better solution.

Comment: @Madhu When i updating my service reference in client project am getting the type name servicereference1 does not  not exist in the type servicereference1  reference.cs